# Javascript innerHTML code not working

Tags: jquery, html, replace

I've searched a lot, I can find a solution but not how I want it, I know it should be possible to use a menu link (a div) as a trigger to change HTML in a div element within the document, but I can not find the way to do it. This is the code I've got so far:

target DIV (HTML):

```
<div id="mainContent" class="content"><!-- content will be loaded here --></div>
```

trigger menu (HMTL):

```
<a id="load_test" href="#"><div class="menu">Services</div></a>
```

CSS is not important in this case... So here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#load_test").click(function(){
        $('#mainContent').html("<object type='text/html' data='test.html'></object>");
    })
});
```

This is what I did wrong within the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

they needed to be switch:

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wront with this code. Any errors on the console?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: You need to include jQuery for jQuery code to work. Hence the ReferenceError

Comment: For me, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/lexingtonpenguins/LdvdH/

Comment: seriously I did not know the jQuery file must be inserted BEFORE the js file. Just had to switch 2 <script> tags in the <head> area and it worked, I feel stupid now ;)

Comment: @RobvandenBogaert We all make mistakes, another set of eyes is always useful. I am sure you look at this for a while and ready to just growl eh :)

Answer (score 0):

use an iframe to load your test.html page and make sure to include jQuery files before your script

```
$( function() {
    $("#load_test").click(function(){
        $('#mainContent').html("<iframe src='test.html' width='100' height='100'></iframe>");
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, input jQuery into the console and see if it is defined or not. If it is, try this:

```
(function($) { 
    $("#load_test").click(function(){
        $('#mainContent').html("<object type='text/html' data='test.html'></object>");
    })
})(jQuery);
```

If not, there's probably something wrong with the way you are including your scripts.